# Is it possible to have REM relative to a parent element?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I am trying to add rem font-sizes to a new section of an existing page.

when I set base font size to HTML tag like this

```
html{
  font-size: 40px;
}
@media #{$medium-only} {
   html{
    font-size: 30px;
   }
}
@media #{$small-only} {
   html{
    font-size: 20px;
   } 
}
```

the font size of rest of the page gets screwed out. Is there a way to do this by setting font size to parent element instead of HTML? I am guessing not from my research but just wanted to check here once.

Comment: Have you looked into `em` and `%` units?

Comment: Yes, actually at first I did using %. Then I started reading up on REM being modern and better approach. So I was trying to implement that.

Comment: Eh... REM is ANOTHER approach, there is nothing more "modern" about it, and basing it off of px-based starting points is still not correct.

Comment: Echo junkfoodjunkie, you should be setting % html font sizes then using rem for the areas you need else your not really achieving anything - px values are fixed sizes.